# Sending custom headers through RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Given my API consumers are required to send a customer HTTP header like this:

```
# curl -H 'X-SomeHeader: 123' http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/api_call.json
```

Then I can read this header in a before_filter method like this:

```
# app/controllers/api_controller.rb
class ApiController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :log_request

private
    def log_request
        logger.debug "Header: #{request.env['HTTP_X_SOMEHEADER']}"
        ...
    end
end
```

So far great. Now I would like to test this using RSpec as there is a change in behavior:

```
# spec/controllers/api_controller_spec.rb
describe ApiController do
    it "should process the header" do
        @request.env['HTTP_X_SOMEHEADER'] = '123'
        get :api_call
        ...
    end
end
```

However, the `request` received in ApiController will not be able to find the header variable.

When trying the `same code` with the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header, it will work. Are custom headers filtered somewhere?

PS: Some examples around the web use `request` instead of `@request`. While I'm not certain which one is correct as of the current Rails 3.2/RSpec 2.14 combination - both methods will not trigger the right behavior, BUT both work with `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

well, maybe too late for people but just to be lined up:

```
it 'should get profile when authorized' do
  user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  request.headers[EMAIL_TOKEN] = user.email
  request.headers[AUTH_TOKEN] = user.authentication_token
  get :profile
  response.should be success
end
```

just call request.headers with appropriate settings.

Comment: @request is nil for me

Comment: sorry, fixed, should be without @

Comment: `request` is also nil

Comment: make sure u have "render_views" under ur controller spec file

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've tried @request.headers['X-DeviceId'] = 'fd243cde'` (also `request`...). The header will not arrive. Is this in a controller spec? Are you able to read the value in a before_filter?

Comment: @SebastianRoth You need to define the header with HTTP at the beginning, the rest in all caps, and use underscores instead of dashes.  e.g @request.headers['HTTP_X_DEVICEID'] = 'foo'

Comment: The difference for me was that I was trying `get :index, {param => value}, {header => value}` when in actual fact I wanted to set the request headers _first_, using `request[header] = value; get :index, param => value`. Thanks!

Comment: I could run it with `rspec-rails (3.4.0)`  and `rails (4.2.5)`

Answer (score 12):

You can define it in `get` directly.

```
get :api_call, nil, {'HTTP_FOO'=>'BAR'}
```

I just verified it works in console.

Comment: Sorry - your answer came in just as I tested this as well. Please see the update. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again - I've tried this as well and it will not work for me. Have you successfully tested this in a RSpec Controller spec?

Comment: I request with this header, and then I ask for `request.env`, this header appears. `get` is Rails's `ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers` method, not Rspec. I did not do it in Rspec but I'm 100% sure it will work the same.

Comment: As said, I've added `@request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = 'en'` as well - this works and the variable can be read using `request.env`. Seems like there is a filter going which I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think @BillyChan is correct the problem is you should not read the header from `request.env` but from `request.headers` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

custom headers won't be included in `request.env` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bdf1a2e7b9096889321f7653a0ccca628a089e2f/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L28-L43

Comment: @BillyChan would you be able to test it in RSpec?

Comment: for me, with Rails 4.2.0, it works without the "nil": get :api_call, {'HTTP_FOO'=>'BAR'}

Comment: this is exactly what i'm trying to do ... I can specify certain headers ('Authorization: token token=...') but not others (my custom 'Session_Token' header).

Answer (score 7):

RSpec request specs [changed in Rails 5](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) so that custom `headers` and `params` must now be defined using key-value hash arguments.  E.g.:

Before in ***Rails 4***:

```
it "creates a Widget and redirects to the Widget's page" do
  headers = { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json" }
  post "/widgets", '{ "widget": { "name":"My Widget" } }', headers
  expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:widget))
end
```

Now for **Rails 5:**

```
it "creates a Widget and redirects to the Widget's page" do
  headers = { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json" }
  post "/widgets", :params => '{ "widget": { "name":"My Widget" } }', :headers => headers
  expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:widget))
end
```

Comment: My result - this just adds a "headers" section into params.  The headers the server receives are always {"HTTPS"=>"off", "HTTP_HOST"=>"example.org", "HTTP_COOKIE"=>""} - and where those are defined, or how to alter them, is unknown.