# Cant set custom header params with rspec and Grape

Tags: ruby, rspec, grape-api

I use Grape api and i need to write a test with custom header

my code:

```
  it "should accept message" do
    post "/api/v1/my/route", post_data, secret: "ASDFGHJKL"
    last_response.status.should == 201
  end
```

but the route gets no headers at all,
i also tried `headers['secret'] = "ASDFGHJKL"`
and also `request.env['secret']`
nothing works.

how can i pass headers in rspec to grape route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `header 'secret', 'ASDFGHJKL'`?

[More on the rack-test docs](http://rdoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/Session%3aheader)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@request` variable, e.g. `@request.env['secret'] = 'ASDF..'`. Hope this helps.

Also, take a look at this - [Sending custom headers through RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438271/sending-custom-headers-through-rspec)