In Rspec, how can I set a login token (http header) in every test without having to pass it as an argument to every http request
I'm writing an integration for an API that requires an authentication header. But authentication is not part of the test itself, and I would like to avoid setting the header in every single get/post I make in the test.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyController, type: :request do


  before do
    # Generates auth token
    post my_login_path, params: { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password' }
    auth_token = JSON.parse(response.body)['auth_token']

    # Set auth token in all future requests
    request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = "Bearer #{auth_token}"
  end

  describe 'example' do
    it 'should return 200' do
      # In my tests I would like to chain several requests
      # together to test some functionality in my API,
      # and I would like to avoid passing a header
      # each time I make a request
      get my_example_path
      post another_example_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status 

    end
  end
end


I'd use a before hook. You might want to share a little more details.

that would be the intention, but I cant find a method to set the headers for the subsequent requests.

Sure, I updated the code with what I'm trying to achieve

Sure, hopefully now it's clearer. Sorry for the confusion.

BTW, it's probably faster to generate the auth token directly instead of having an additional POST request.

@Andredriem When you run the code shown in your question what happens? In the controller actions don't you get the auth token (you set in the before hook) in request? If yes, then try request.headers['your_header_name'] = 'your_header_value'. Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635204/936494. Thanks.

@JigneshGohel Thanks for the response. But setting it directly in request headers didn't work.

I didn't find a solution for setting default headers in all requests, in the end I ended up creating an easily stubbed method in my controller:
class MyController
    def authorization_header
        request.headers['Authorization']
    end

    def function_that_authenticates_headers
      header = authorization_header
      #... rest of authentication logic
    end

    # ...
end

And then when setting up my test I only need to stub the authorization_header
describe MyController do
    before do
        # Generates auth token
        post my_login_path, params: { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password' }
        auth_token = JSON.parse(response.body)['auth_token']
    
        # Set auth token in all future requests
        allow_any_instance_of(MyController).to receive(:authorization_header).and_return("Bearer #{auth_token}")
    end 

    # ... rest of tests
end

I would still prefer a solution where I can set a default header in my requests without stubbing, but I couldn't find any.

One thing this could be telling you is that authorization logic probably doesn't actually belong in the controller but rather a separate component thats easy to stub. One of the great things about Warden for example is how it easy test mode makes it to fake authentication.

You are absolutely wright.

There is also another component to this which is acuity vs test performance. You obviously want to test your authentication system properly in at least one spec but if all your request specs have to send an additional HTTP request in its setup phase it adds significant overhead which will slow your tests suite. In that case stubbing the auth system is actually the right thing to do.
